# How to subscribe to Topic in Dapr for .Net Core outside Controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, dapr

I just started with Dapr a few days back and although I am able to publish and subscribe to events in Dapr, the way I am doing so is using the **Topic** method attribute on an action method within a controller such as this...

[image]

And while this works I prefer not to mix integration events with service API. This is the Swagger...

[image]

I get that the topic name is long but it's so I can ensure unique topics.

What I'd prefer is to position the Handler outside of any Controller. Something like this..

[image]

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I derived a solution out of the .Net Dapr client routing sample.

For each event I add a **MapPost** endpoint similar to the following

[image]

The **RequestDelegator** receives the event for a given Topic, it will resolve the handler class from the interface and topic attributes and then invoke it's handle method, passing in the event data from Dapr.

[image]

My services follow the CQRS and EventSourcing patterns, as such integration events will rarely be the same shape as the command inputs. In my case, events are typically much lighter than a commands, consisting of mostly related Ids.